# Is there an \allowenlargepage{...}?

Tags: typography

I have sections that flow over into the following page by about 1 or 2 `\baselineskip`s.  This is easy to solve with an `\enlargethispage{}` and prevents the 2-line widows. Lateron, I may make a few more changes, and everything reflows.  Now the problem is that the page with the `enlargethispage` is still a little longer, unless I go back and remove it.

What I would rather tell latex is to be more tolerant just on this particular page about to meet its widowing niceness criteria, and that it should only apply at the current page.

Easy or hard?

Comment: Perhaps you should rather focus on such adjustments only towards the end of the document, for exactly the reasons you mention ("...Later on, I may make a few more changes, ...").

Comment: Very related: [page breaking - automatically to apply \enlargethispage{\baselineskip} when single-word-widow occurs - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96039/automatically-to-apply-enlargethispage-baselineskip-when-single-word-widow-oc) // See also: [How do I prevent widow/orphan lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-do-i-prevent-widow-orphan-lines)

Comment: hard, but one thing  is not to use `\enlargethispage` directly use a custom command such as `\WibbleChapterAenlargethispage` then you can easily define that to be nothing and reflow that chapter adding them back if needed without disturbing the rest of the document.

Comment: It would be quite difficult to implement such a command, that needs trial runs of the output routine in order to decide whether the next page really has widow lines. Besides, if you use twoside typesetting, both pages in a spread should be enlarged, so you see that the problem is unsolvable. Leave such decision to the final revision step.

Comment: the problem is that my books are *never* full finished.  I think they are finished, but then comes another change.   this is worse for my almost done book on climate change (https://www.ivo-welch.info/teaching/moving-the-needle/), where not a day goes by without something else being interesting.   (yes, I want a `\WibbleChapterAenlargethispage`.)  I think widowpenalty solves the problem not with an `\enlargethispage` but with an earlier break only.